# Import data from files xlsx with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 table `SQL`, I fill them by 2 file `xlsx` by `PHP`
I did a class just for the getters and setters, and other classe for the request `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT`.
When I test if I read the data from the files it return nothing and of course my table do not update.
the code is the following:

```
public function save(\....\Parse\LRU $LRU){

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($LRU); //// it do not return any thing
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
    $IdLRU = $LRU->getId();
    if ($LRU == "Unspecified") {
        $IdLRU = 40;
    } else {
        if ($LRU != 'new'){
            $check= $this->_db->query("SELECT `ID_LRU` FROM `lru` WHERE `LRU` ='".$LRU->getLRU()."'");

            if ($check->rowCount() == 0) {
                $this->_db->query("INSERT INTO `lru` (`ID_LRU`, `LRU`) VALUES ('".$LRU->getId()."' , '".$LRU->getLRU()."');");
                $requete2 =$this->_db->query("SELECT `ID_LRU` FROM `lru` WHERE `LRU` ='".$LRU->getLRU()."'");
                while($data = $requete2->fetch()) {
                    $IdLRU=$data['ID_LRU'];
                }

                echo($this->_db->query);    
            } else {
                while($data = $check->fetch()) {
                    $IdLRU=$data['ID_LRU'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

} 

public function saveAll(array $LRUdao) {
    $count=0;
    foreach ($LRUdao as $value) {
        if($this->save($value))
        $count++;
    }
    return $count; //// of course here it return 0, 
    echo($count);
}
```

Can you tell me please where is the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: **Could it be something to do with** the contents of **LINE 6** which is a **`die();`**

Comment: Thank you for a guide to debug my code. the die(); and the same 4 lines  it works well in other class. And I tried the test without die();  nothing is change.